# unable to convert dex format unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, sdk

I can't build in unity5.4.1f1 because whenever I'm trying to build my game into Android platform it says:

> unable to convert dex format unity

Here's the error I got:

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to convert classes into dex format.
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\bin\java.exe -Xmx2048M -    Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-        sdk\tools" -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar "C:\Program         Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\sdktools.jar" -

stderr[
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already     added: Lcom/google/protobuf/nano/CodedInputByteBufferNano;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already     added: Lcom/google/protobuf/nano/CodedOutputByteBufferNano;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already     added:     Lcom/google/protobuf/nano/CodedOutputByteBufferNano$OutOfSpaceException;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already     added: Lcom/google/protobuf/nano/ExtendableMessageNano;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already     added: Lcom/google/protobuf/nano/Extension;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/protobuf/nano/Extension$1;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/protobuf/nano/Extension$PrimitiveExtension;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/protobuf/nano/FieldArray;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/protobuf/nano/FieldData;

UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Translation has been interrupted
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:613)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:311)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at     sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.    java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at SDKMain.main(SDKMain.java:129)
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException: Too many errors
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:605)
... 9 more
]
stdout[
processing archive     C:\Users\Nette\Documents\LearnSomethingNewThesis\Temp\StagingArea\android-    libraries\gvr_android_common\libs\.\classes.jar...
ignored resource META-INF/
ignored resource META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
ignored resource clearcut/
ignored resource clearcut/nano/
processing clearcut/nano/EventCodeEnumProto.class...
ignored resource com/
ignored resource com/google/
ignored resource com/google/common/
ignored resource com/google/common/logging/
ignored resource com/google/common/logging/nano/
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Eventid.class...
processing     com/google/common/logging/nano/Eventid$ClientEventIdMessage.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Eventid$EventIdMessage.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/GmmInteractionKeyInfo.class...
processing     com/google/common/logging/nano/GmmInteractionKeyInfo$GMMInteractionKeyInfo.cl    ass...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/GwsInteractionKeyInfo.class...
processing     com/google/common/logging/nano/GwsInteractionKeyInfo$GWSInteractionKeyInfo.cl    ass...
processing     com/google/common/logging/nano/GwsInteractionKeyInfo$SignedInUserStatus.class    ...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/InteractionKey.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/RequestContext.class...
processing     com/google/common/logging/nano/RequestContext$GWSRequestContext.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/RequestContext$UIState.class...
processing     com/google/common/logging/nano/RequestContext$UIState$ToggleState.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/UserActionEnum.class...
processing     com/google/common/logging/nano/UserActionEnum$CardinalDirection.class...
processing     com/google/common/logging/nano/UserActionEnum$UserAction.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$Application.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$AudioStats.class...
processing     com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$AudioStats$RenderingMode.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$Bucket.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$Cyclops.class...
processing     com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$Cyclops$Capture.class...
processing     com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$Cyclops$Capture$Outcome.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$Cyclops$Share.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$Cyclops$Share$Type.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$Cyclops$View.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$Cyclops$View$Orientation.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$EmbedVrWidget.class...
processing     com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$EmbedVrWidget$Pano.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$EmbedVrWidget$StereoFormat.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$EmbedVrWidget$Video.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$EmbedVrWidget$ViewMode.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$EventType.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$HeadMount.class...
processing     com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$HistogramBucket.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$PerformanceStats.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$QrCodeScan.class...
processing     com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$QrCodeScan$Status.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$SensorStats.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$SensorStats$GyroscopeStats.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$SensorStats$Vector3.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$TimeSeriesData.class...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$TimeSeriesData$TimeIntervalData.cla    ss...
processing com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$VrCore.class...
processing     com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$VrCore$ErrorCode.class...
processing     com/google/common/logging/nano/Vr$VREvent$VrCore$Permission.class...
ignored resource com/google/protobuf/
ignored resource com/google/protobuf/nano/
processing com/google/protobuf/nano/CodedInputByteBufferNano.class...
processing com/google/protobuf/nano/CodedOutputByteBufferNano.class...
processing     com/google/protobuf/nano/CodedOutputByteBufferNano$OutOfSpaceException.class.    ..
processing com/google/protobuf/nano/DescriptorProtos.class...
processing     com/google/protobuf/nano/DescriptorProtos$DescriptorProto.class...
processing     com/google/protobuf/nano/DescriptorProtos$DescriptorProto$ExtensionRange.clas    s...
processing     com/google/protobuf/nano/DescriptorProtos$DescriptorProto$ReservedRange.class    ...
 processing com/google/protobuf/nano/DescriptorProtos$EnumDescriptorProto.class...
processing com/google/protobuf/nano/DescriptorProtos$EnumOptions.class...
processing     com/google/protobuf/nano/DescriptorProtos$EnumValueDescriptorProto.class...
processing com/google/protobuf/nano/DescriptorProtos$EnumValueOptions.class...
processing com/google/protobuf/nano/DescriptorProtos$FieldDescriptorProto.class...
processing com/google/protobuf/nano/DescriptorProtos$FieldDescriptorProto$Label.class...
processing com/google/protobuf/nano/DescriptorProtos$FieldDescriptorProto$Type.class...
processing com/google/protobuf/nano/DescriptorProtos$FieldOptions.class...
processing com/google/protobuf/nano/DescriptorProtos$FieldOptions$CType.class...
processing com/google/protobuf/nano/DescriptorProtos$FieldOptions$JSType.class...
processing com/google/protobuf/nano/DescriptorProtos$FieldOptions$JType.class...
processing com/google/protobuf/nano/DescriptorProtos$FieldOptions$UpgradedOption.class..    .
processing com/google/protobuf/nano/DescriptorProtos$FileDescriptorProto.class...
processing com/google/protobuf/nano/DescriptorProtos$FileDescriptorSet.class...
processing com/google/protobuf/nano/DescriptorProtos$FileOptions.class...
processing com/google/protobuf/nano/DescriptorProtos$FileOptions$CompatibilityLevel.clas    s...
processing com/google/protobuf/nano/DescriptorProtos$FileOptions$OptimizeMode.class...
processing com/google/protobuf/nano/DescriptorProtos$GeneratedCodeInfo.class...
processing com/google/protobuf/nano/DescriptorProtos$GeneratedCodeInfo$Annotation.class.    ..
processing com/google/protobuf/nano/DescriptorProtos$MessageOptions.class...
processing com/google/protobuf/nano/DescriptorProtos$MethodDescriptorProto.class...
processing com/google/protobuf/nano/DescriptorProtos$MethodOptions.class...
processing com/google/protobuf/nano/DescriptorProtos$MethodOptions$Format.class...
processing com/google/protobuf/nano/DescriptorProtos$MethodOptions$LogLevel.class...
processing com/google/protobuf/nano/DescriptorProtos$MethodOptions$Protocol.class...
processing com/google/protobuf/nano/DescriptorProtos$MethodOptions$SecurityLevel.class..    .
processing com/google/protobuf/nano/DescriptorProtos$MethodOptions$TokenUnit.class...
processing com/google/protobuf/nano/DescriptorProtos$OneofDescriptorProto.class...
processing com/google/protobuf/nano/DescriptorProtos$OneofOptions.class...
processing com/google/protobuf/nano/DescriptorProtos$ServiceDescriptorProto.class...
processing     com/google/protobuf/nano/DescriptorProtos$ServiceOptions.class...
processing com/google/protobuf/nano/DescriptorProtos$SourceCodeInfo.class...
processing com/google/protobuf/nano/DescriptorProtos$SourceCodeInfo$Location.class...
processing com/google/protobuf/nano/DescriptorProtos$StreamDescriptorProto.class...
processing com/google/protobuf/nano/DescriptorProtos$StreamOptions.class...
processing com/google/protobuf/nano/DescriptorProtos$StreamOptions$TokenUnit.class...
processing com/google/protobuf/nano/DescriptorProtos$UninterpretedOption.class...
processing com/google/protobuf/nano/DescriptorProtos$UninterpretedOption$NamePart.class.    ..
processing com/google/protobuf/nano/ExtendableMessageNano.class...
processing com/google/protobuf/nano/Extension.class...
processing com/google/protobuf/nano/Extension$1.class...
processing com/google/protobuf/nano/Extension$PrimitiveExtension.class...
processing com/google/protobuf/nano/FieldArray.class...
processing com/google/protobuf/nano/FieldData.class...
processing com/google/protobuf/nano/InternalNano.class...
processing com/google/protobuf/nano/InvalidProtocolBufferNanoException.class...
processing com/google/protobuf/nano/MessageNano.class...
processing com/google/protobuf/nano/MessageNanoPrinter.class...
processing com/google/protobuf/nano/UnknownFieldData.class...
processing com/google/protobuf/nano/WireFormatNano.class...
ignored resource com/google/protobuf/nano/android/
processing     com/google/protobuf/nano/android/ParcelableExtendableMessageNano.class...
processing     com/google/protobuf/nano/android/ParcelableMessageNano.class...
processing     com/google/protobuf/nano/android/ParcelableMessageNanoCreator.class...
ignored resource com/google/protos/
ignored resource com/google/protos/datapol/
ignored resource com/google/protos/datapol/nano/
processing com/google/protos/datapol/nano/RetentionAnnotations.class...
processing com/google/protos/datapol/nano/RetentionAnnotations$RetentionSpec.class...
processing com/google/protos/datapol/nano/RetentionAnnotations$RetentionTag.class...
processing com/google/protos/datapol/nano/SemanticAnnotations.class...
processing com/google/protos/datapol/nano/SemanticAnnotations$DataFormat.class...
processing com/google/protos/datapol/nano/SemanticAnnotations$FieldDetails.class...
processing com/google/protos/datapol/nano/SemanticAnnotations$LocationQualifier.class...
processing com/google/protos/datapol/nano/SemanticAnnotations$MessageDetails.class...
processing com/google/protos/datapol/nano/SemanticAnnotations$Qualifier.class...
processing com/google/protos/datapol/nano/SemanticAnnotations$SemanticType.class...
ignored resource com/google/search/
ignored resource com/google/search/onenamespace/
ignored resource com/google/search/onenamespace/nano/
processing com/google/search/onenamespace/nano/OneNamespaceType.class...
ignored resource com/google/vr/
ignored resource com/google/vr/cardboard/
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/AndroidNCompat.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/AndroidNCompat$1.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/AndroidNCompat$2.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/AndroidNCompat$3.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/CardboardGLSurfaceView.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/CardboardGLSurfaceView$DetachListener.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/ConfigUtils.class...
processing     com/google/vr/cardboard/ContentProviderVrParamsProvider.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/DisplaySynchronizer.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/DisplayUtils.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/EglFactory.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/FrameMonitor.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/FullscreenMode.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/FullscreenMode$1.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/FullscreenMode$1$1.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/GLTextureView.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/GLTextureView$1.class...
processing     com/google/vr/cardboard/GLTextureView$BaseConfigChooser.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/GLTextureView$ComponentSizeChooser.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/GLTextureView$DefaultContextFactory.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/GLTextureView$DefaultWindowSurfaceFactory.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/GLTextureView$EglHelper.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/GLTextureView$GLThread.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/GLTextureView$GLThreadManager.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/GLTextureView$LogWriter.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/GLTextureView$SimpleEGLConfigChooser.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/GLTextureView$TraceCompat.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/LegacyVrParamsProvider.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/NFCUtils.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/NFCUtils$1.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/NativeLibraryLoader.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/PackageUtils.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/PerfMonitor.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/PerfMonitor$1.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/PermissionUtils.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/PhoneParams.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/PhoneParams$PpiOverride.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/ScanlineRacingRenderer.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/TransitionView.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/TransitionView$1.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/TransitionView$2.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/TransitionView$3.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/TransitionView$4.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/TransitionView$5.class...
processing     com/google/vr/cardboard/TransitionView$TransitionListener.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/UiLayer.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/UiLayer$1.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/UiLayer$10.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/UiLayer$11.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/UiLayer$12.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/UiLayer$2.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/UiLayer$3.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/UiLayer$4.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/UiLayer$5.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/UiLayer$6.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/UiLayer$7.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/UiLayer$8.class...
processing com/google/vr/cardboard/UiLayer$9.class...<message truncated>
```

Comment: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/672365/unable-to-convert-classes-into-dex-format.html  The error log is quite similar to yours. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already     added: Lcom/google/protobuf/nano/CodedInputByteBufferNano;
```

This is the Problem. Somewhere in your project you have a duplicate android library. Unity is trying to convert all the classes to dex format but it's getting duplicates and it doesn't like that.

All you need to do is find the offending library and delete one of the copies. Doesn't matter which one.

Most likely the library will be a .jar file.